# Get common elements (from the same row) between to columns of comma separated strings, preserving rownames

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with some column containing comma separated strings:

```
     colA     colB

1    a,b,c,ñ  d,b,e
2    f,g,h    f,g,m,p
3    i,j,k    f,o,j
```

I would like to get common elements between both columns corresponding to the same row. So my desired output is:

```
    colA    colB
1     b       b
2    f,g     f,g
3     j       j
```

I was trying to transform this columns to lists of lists to perform an intersection after that, but I am having some problems, so I would like to know if there is something easier. How can I get this?

Comment: Do you really want to replace the columns? If the results are going to be the same for "colA" and "colB", do you really need to store the intersection of both in two columns?

Comment: Yes, actually I don't mind if I preserve both or one column. Maybe one would be more efficient

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we can use this

```
 df[,1:2] <- apply(df,1, function(X) paste(unlist(strsplit(X[1],","))[unlist(strsplit(X[1],",")) %in% unlist(strsplit(X[2],","))],collapse=",") )


   > df
  colA colB
1    b    b
2  f,g  f,g
3    j    j
```

---

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(colA = structure(1:3, .Label = c("a,b,c,ñ", "f,g,h", 
"i,j,k"), class = "factor"), colB = structure(1:3, .Label = c("d,b,e", 
"f,g,m,p", "f,o,j"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're dealing with a larger dataset, you can try `cSplit_l` from "splitstackshape":

```
library(splitstackshape)
temp <- cSplit_l(df, names(df), ",", stripWhite = TRUE, type.convert = FALSE, drop = TRUE)
temp[, 1:2] <- vapply(Map(intersect, temp[[1]], temp[[2]]), toString, character(1L))
setnames(temp, names(df))[]
##    colA colB
## 1:    b    b
## 2: f, g f, g
## 3:    j    j
```

It's not clear why you would want the same content in both these columns.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>% 
   transmute(colA = map_chr(str_extract_all(colA, 
              str_replace_all(colB, ",", "|")), toString), 
          colB = colA)
#   colA colB
#1    b    b
#2 f, g f, g
#3    j    j
```