# Comparing character lists in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, intersect

I have two lists of characters that i read in from excel files
One is a very long list of all bird species that have been documented in a region (`allBirds`) and another is a list of species that were recently seen in a sample location (`sampleBirds`), which is much shorter.  I want to write a section of code that will compare the lists and tell me which `sampleBirds` show up in the `allBirds` list. Both are lists of characters.

I have tried:

```
# upload xlxs file
Full_table <- read_excel("Full_table.xlsx")
Pathogen_table <- read_excel("pathogens.xlsx")

# read species columnn into a new dataframe
species <-c(as.data.frame(Full_table[,7], drop=FALSE))
pathogens <- c(as.data.frame(Pathogen_table[,3], drop=FALSE))

intersect(pathogens, species)

intersect(species, pathogens)
```

but intersect is outputting lists of 0, which I know cannot be true, any suggestions?

Comment: check out `semi_join` from the `dplyr` package

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO : please read `?dput` in `R`  and post a small sample of your datasets.  That way we can see whether the values are compatible (class type) and whether they really are the same, or have different capitalization, white space, and so on.

Comment: Is your problem anything like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62454705/get-common-elements-from-the-same-row-between-to-columns-of-comma-separated-st)? As @CarlWitthoft said, it's much easier to get help if you post a small sample of data similar to what you're actually working with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run the intersect on the individual columns that are stored in the list:

```
> a <- c(data.frame(c1=as.factor(c('a', 'q'))))
> b <- c(data.frame(c1=as.factor(c('w', 'a'))))
> intersect(a,b)
list()
> intersect(a$c1,b$c1)
[1] "a"
```

This will probably do in your case

```
intersect(Full_table[,7], Pathogen_table[,3])
```

Or if you insist on creating the data.frames:

```
intersect(pathogens[1,], species[1,])
```

where `[1,]` should select the first column of the data.frame only. Note that by using `c(as.data.frame(...` you are converting the `data.frame` to a regular list. I'd go with only `as.data.frame(...`.

Comment: Does this work if the lists are different lengths? I tried to do it without creating the dataframes but it output the error "Must subset rows with a valid subscript vector. Logical subscripts must match the size of the indexed input. Input has size 206 but subscript `!duplicated(x, fromLast = fromLast, ...)` has size 0."

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try `match()` function or `"=="`.